# List multiple inputs in a row

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js, grid-system

I wonder if there is a way to show inputs type-text `col-md-6`. I want them to list top to bottom like this.

[image]

Ex.

Right now, I had to create more row per input.

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="temperature"
            :rules="form.rules.url"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>

<v-row>
    <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="temperature"
            :rules="form.rules.url"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

I was hoping I can do something like this, seems cleaner, but If I do that, it goes side by side. That's not what I wanted.

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="temperature"
            :rules="form.rules.url"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="temperature"
            :rules="form.rules.url"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>


</v-row>
```

Comment: As I know bootstrap grid-system is defined according to 12 columns in each row. So how could you expect that the second input in the **same** row wraps onto a new line when each input has ```col-6``` width? Maybe [that happens](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#column-wrapping), if you have two input that each one has ```col-8``` width

Comment: Another way to do that is to have col-6 for input, and col-6 empty. but I just want to know if vuetify have a way to do that without a hack.

Comment: But I think this is the logic of ```v-row``` in vuetify. It is defined to keep the elements inside itself in a **single** row. I could not understand the exact goal of you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex-column` to `<v-row>`. This will solve your problem. If it is not solved please try to provide `flex-direction: column;` to the wrapping parent.